# Trouble with SQL using constraint and foreign key

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm learning to use MYSQL (on Xamp app for Mac OS X with MariaDB) and I'm stuck...

When I want to alter table to add constraint with foreign key, I get this error:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_forum`.`#sql-2d52_2f4`, CONSTRAINT `CO_FK_message` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_message`) REFERENCES `T_message` (`ID_message`))

But I just did the EXACT action before in my script (for another table) and it work just fine ...

I already looked here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html but didn't helped at all.

The error appear only with the last 4 lines.

Here is my script:

```
/* commentaire debggg drop */
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_forum;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_forum;
USE db_forum;


CREATE TABLE T_message
(
ID_message int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
text_MSG VARCHAR(255),
datecrea_MSG DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_message)
)ENGINE = InnoDB ;


CREATE TABLE T_user
(
ID_user int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
prenom_user VARCHAR(50),
nom_user VARCHAR(50),
datenaissance_user DATE NOT NULL,
email_user VARCHAR(30),
account_user VARCHAR(16),
password_user VARCHAR(16),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_user)
)ENGINE = InnoDB ;


CREATE TABLE T_thread
(
ID_thread int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
datecrea_thread DATE NOT NULL,
titre_thread VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_thread)
)ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE T_posted
(
ID_posted int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FK_user int NOT NULL,
FK_message int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_posted),
CONSTRAINT CO_FK_message FOREIGN KEY (FK_message) REFERENCES T_message (ID_message),
CONSTRAINT CO_FK_user FOREIGN KEY (FK_user) REFERENCES T_user (ID_user)
)ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE T_manyMSG
(
ID_manyMSG int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FK_thread int NOT NULL,
FK_message int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_manyMSG),
CONSTRAINT CO_FK_thread FOREIGN KEY (FK_thread) REFERENCES T_thread (id_thread),
CONSTRAINT CO_FK_MSG FOREIGN KEY (FK_message) REFERENCES T_message (id_message)
)ENGINE = InnoDB ;


/* IMPORTE DATA */

/* table T_user/ AJOUT DATA */
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Volumes/Local_SSD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/forum/sql/import_data_user.csv'

    INTO TABLE T_user

    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (prenom_user,nom_user,datenaissance_user,email_user,account_user,password_user);

    /* ajout manuel de compte administrateur pour forum et compte test */   
INSERT INTO T_user (prenom_user, nom_user, datenaissance_user, email_user, account_user, password_user )
VALUES ('Joel', 'lawl', '1990-10-20','lol@lil.com','admin','1234'),
('bernard', 'plowz', '1980-11-22','lo@ll.com','test','12345');


/* table T_message / AJOUT DATA */
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Volumes/Local_SSD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/forum/sql/import_data_message.csv'

    INTO TABLE T_message

    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (text_MSG,datecrea_MSG);

/* AJOUT MANUEL POUR TEST */    
INSERT INTO T_message (text_MSG, datecrea_MSG)
VALUES ('bonjour','2016-01-20'),
('salut','2016-02-20');

/* Desactivation des FK_message pour ajout de data dans table / T_posted */
/* ATTENTION Ceci prend effet après 1 minutes */
/* ATTENTION, CES COMMANDES FONCTIONE PARFAITEMENT AVEC L'ENGINE SERVEUR MARIADB (SUR XAMP MAC OS X) */

ALTER TABLE `db_forum`.`T_posted` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `CO_FK_message`;
ALTER TABLE `db_forum`.`T_posted` 
DROP INDEX `CO_FK_message` ;



/* Desactivation des FK_user pour ajout de data dans table / T_posted */
/* ATTENTION Ceci prend effet après 1 minutes */
/* ATTENTION, CES COMMANDES FONCTIONE PARFAITEMENT AVEC L'ENGINE SERVEUR MARIADB (SUR XAMP MAC OS X) */

ALTER TABLE `db_forum`.`T_posted` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `CO_FK_user`;
ALTER TABLE `db_forum`.`T_posted` 
DROP INDEX `CO_FK_user` ;


/* table T_posted * AJOUT DATA */
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Volumes/Local_SSD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/forum/sql/import_data_posted.csv'

    INTO TABLE T_posted     

    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (FK_user,FK_message);

/* AJOUT MANUEL POUR TEST JOIN */
INSERT INTO T_posted (FK_user, FK_message)
VALUES ('128','1024'),
('129','1025');



/* THIS ONE WORK */ 

ALTER TABLE T_posted
ADD CONSTRAINT CO_FK_user
FOREIGN KEY (FK_user)
REFERENCES T_user(ID_user);

/* THIS ONE DONT WORK =/ */ 

ALTER TABLE T_posted
ADD CONSTRAINT CO_FK_message
FOREIGN KEY (FK_message)
REFERENCES T_message(ID_message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not in your ALTER TABLE statement.

You when you insert the data, you should check that there are not problems with the restrictions.

It seems you are inserting a foreign key that doesn't exist as primary key.

You should also, make the ALTER statements before inserting the data.

Best regards,

Comment: Actually, it work like it:
1) I create table with constraint and foreign linked.
2) I Drop them for insert data (they fit right into tables).
3) I Alter Table to add the constraint and foreign Key again.

I also tried step by step, it work fine (adding data, adding the first Constraint), so i dont think that's the problem ?

Comment: If the the data is well structured. Adding again the foreign keys should not be a problem. I think you have to check the data from the tables T_message and T_posted. Check if there is one or more FK_Message (from T_posted) that doesn't exist as ID_message (from T_message).

Comment: Ok, thx a lot, i will look at this tomorrow and update if resolved.

Comment: I tried to run All my script without importing anything, work just fine, so the SQL code is correct, the trouble comes from my datas.

Thanks a lot from your help !

Comment: Good to hear that :)